# Power BI: List duplicates from a table for a combination of columns

Tags: powerbi, duplicates, powerquery, m

I have below the table sourced from Flat file:

| DATE | STATE | CODE | GROUP | TYPE | ITEM | COST |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/02/2023 | TX | C1 | G1 | T1 | I1 | 1.234 |
| 01/02/2023 | TX | C1 | G1 | T1 | I2 | 1.234 |
| 01/02/2023 | TX | C1 | G1 | T1 | I3 | 1.234 |
| 01/02/2023 | TX | C1 | G1 | T1 | I4 | 1.234 |
| 01/03/2023 | PL | C2 | G2 | T3 | I5 | 1.234 |
| 01/03/2023 | PL | C2 | G2 | T3 | I6 | 2.234 |
| 01/03/2023 | PL | C2 | G2 | T3 | I7 | 3.234 |
| 01/03/2023 | PL | C2 | G2 | T3 | I8 | 3.234 |

In a table visual, the requirement is:

- For the combination of Date + State + Code + Group + Type, show all rows (if at least one row has a different COST).
- The first 4 rows should not be displayed since the COST is the same for the above combination.
- The last 4 rows must be displayed since the COSTS are different (note that the last row should also be displayed)

Note:
I have tried groups by, inner join based on a composite key, removing duplicates and all but none yield the results that I am looking for.

> Help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

In PowerQuery, do the following.

1. Group by as follows:
   [image]
2. Highlight first 5 columns and keep duplicates
3. Expand the All column to get ITEM back.
4. Remove the count column as not required

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMjDUNzDSNzIwMlZQ0lEKiQCRzoYg0h1MhoBJTzBpqGdkbKIUq0O0LiOydBmTpcsEU5cxXFeAD1gX2D3uYDIELO5pSpYuMxBpRKoucxBpTKouCyRdsQA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [DATE = _t, STATE = _t, CODE = _t, GROUP = _t, TYPE = _t, ITEM = _t, COST = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"DATE", type date}, {"STATE", type text}, {"CODE", type text}, {"GROUP", type text}, {"TYPE", type text}, {"ITEM", type text}, {"COST", type number}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"DATE", "STATE", "CODE", "GROUP", "TYPE", "COST"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}, {"All", each _, type table [DATE=nullable date, STATE=nullable text, CODE=nullable text, GROUP=nullable text, TYPE=nullable text, ITEM=nullable text, COST=nullable number]}}),
    #"Kept Duplicates" = let columnNames = {"DATE", "STATE", "CODE", "GROUP", "TYPE"}, addCount = Table.Group(#"Grouped Rows", columnNames, {{"Count.1", Table.RowCount, type number}}), selectDuplicates = Table.SelectRows(addCount, each [Count.1] > 1), removeCount = Table.RemoveColumns(selectDuplicates, "Count.1") in Table.Join(#"Grouped Rows", columnNames, removeCount, columnNames, JoinKind.Inner),
    #"Expanded All" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Kept Duplicates", "All", {"ITEM"}, {"ITEM"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded All",{"Count"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch David. I was able to port this and got the visual working. One thing I didn't get is how we can implement the "kept duplicates" using UI steps but it was there in the Keep Rows dropdown. Thanks again